# Separete the graphs to show the ylabel and x label using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a graph but it is terrible. I want to separete the graphs in parts here is how it is:

[image]

The code:

```
  def plot_picture(self, tab):
    try:
        self.df = pd.read_csv(self.file)
    except Exception as e:
        messagebox.showerror("Error", "File not found")
    try:
        dyaw=self.df['Flow'].tolist()
        dsurge=self.df['CH4'].tolist()
        dsway=self.df['CO2'].tolist()
        dheave=self.df['O2'].tolist()
        droll=self.df['H2S'].tolist()
        dpitch=self.df['Ap'].tolist()
        dtime=self.df['Time'].tolist()
        fig2, axs2 = plt.subplots(6, sharex=True, sharey=False, gridspec_kw={'hspace': 0})
        fig2.suptitle('RTVGM Data Time History')
        axs2[0].plot(dtime, dsurge)
        axs2[1].plot(dtime, dsway)
        axs2[2].plot(dtime, dheave)
        axs2[3].plot(dtime, droll)
        axs2[4].plot(dtime, dpitch)
        axs2[5].plot(dtime, dyaw)
        axs2[0].set_ylabel('CH4 (%)',fontsize=6)
        axs2[1].set_ylabel('CO2 (%)',fontsize=6)
        axs2[2].set_ylabel('O2 (%)',fontsize=6)
        axs2[3].set_ylabel('H2S (%)',fontsize=6)
        axs2[4].set_ylabel('Ap (mbar)',fontsize=6)
        axs2[5].set_ylabel('Flow (l/pm)',fontsize=6)
        axs2[5].set_xlabel('Time(# of record)',fontsize=6)
        axs2[0].set_ylim(-1,70)
        axs2[1].set_ylim(-1,40)
        axs2[2].set_ylim(-1,25)
        axs2[3].set_ylim(-10,300)
        axs2[4].set_ylim(1000,1020)
        axs2[5].set_ylim(0,0.5)
        self.frame = ttk.Frame(tab, height=500, width=700)
        self.frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
        canvas2=FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig2,master=self.frame)
        canvas2.get_tk_widget().place(x=0,y=0,width=600,height=400)
        canvas2.draw()
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
        messagebox.showerror("Error", "Not correct file")
```

I want each graph be separete and have limit in y and x. Can you could help me achive it? Maybe using one axes for each, but i don´t know how do it.

Comment: ```plt.subplots(6, sharex=True, sharey=False, gridspec_kw={'hspace': 0})``` Here, you are instructing the graphs to share the x axis and to have no space between them ("height").

Comment: I want something like that fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4, ax5, ax6) = plt.subplots(6, 1), but I don´t know how to use it in my casa